# In JavaScript, how to detect that an iterator returns key-value entries?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following function that tries to implement a generic behavior when it is passed an iterable thing:

```
let f = function(thing) {
    if (typeof thing[Symbol.iterator] === 'function') {
        for (let [key, value] of thing) {
            console.warn(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

If the iterable thing doesn't return key-value pairs when iterated, the key variable will be set to the actual value of the iteration and value will be undefined. I'd like to always retrieve the value, whatever the type of data return by the iterator.

How can I detect that this iterable thing is not returning key-value pairs when iterated?

I can't rely on checking if value is undefined since it is perfectly valid for a key-value iteratable to have a key and an undefined value.

Edit:

A RunKit example that demonstrate that iterating a Map and a Set with that generic function leads to unexpected results with Set:

https://runkit.com/ericmorand/generic-iterable-handler

Comment: Almost feels like the only option is to check for and call a `values()` function which is extremely brittle; there's no guarantee that the interface in question implements that to return a values-only iterator