# Find if a js object only has 'falsey' values recursively

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Let us define a falsey value as one of the following (my own definition) JS values:

- `""` (empty string)
- `0` (zero, or any 'variation' of it, such as 0.0, -0, etc.)
- `false` (boolean)
- `[]` (empty array)
- `{}` (empty object)

I would like to recursively find if an object or array only contains empty values. Here would be a few examples:

- `{"x": 0}` (yes, for object only consider leaf-values)
- `{"x": {"y": [0,0,[]]}}` (yes)
- `[0,0,[],{}]` (yes)
- `[[[]], [], {}]` (yes)
- `[1]` (no)

What might be a way to do this? I'd prefer a functional style since those answers always seems to be the most creative and fun to read!

So far I have something like:

```
let arr = [];
function isEmpty(val) {
    if (typeof(value) === 'object') {
        for (subval of val) {
            arr.push(isEmpty(subval));
        }
    } else {
       arr.push(["", 0, false, [], {}].indexOf(val) !== -1);
    }
}
// now see if the arr is something like [false, false, ...]
```

Comment: You might be looking for [codegolf.se]... Also [there's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: It would be better if your question explained the problems you're having with your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that `[] !== []` and `{} !== {}` which is the comparison `indexOf()` uses so you'll never get any matches for empty arrays and objects.

Instead, for objects and arrays, you can check their iterable values array recursively using [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const isEmpty = (val) => {
  if (!val) {
    // any implicitly falsy value; false, 0, "", null and undefined
    return true;
  }
  
  if (typeof val === "object") {
    // recursively check every value, returns true for an empty collection
    return Object.values(val).every(isEmpty);
  }
  
  // otherwise, it is not empty
  return false;
}

const test = [
  {"x": 0},
  {"x": {"y": [0,0,[]]}},
  [0,0,[],{}],
  [[[]], [], {}],
  [1],
];

test.forEach((val) => {
  console.log(isEmpty(val) ? 'empty' : 'not empty', JSON.stringify(val));
});
```

Note: This only works on object and array literals. Iterators are much harder to [reliably extract values from](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48533198/283366).

Comment: there's technically no need for the `length === 0` check, because `[].every(whatever)` is always true.

Comment: @gog interesting. `Array.prototype.every()` returns `true` for an empty array no matter the predicate. TIL

Comment: yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth